# How to navigate using WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb6

How to navigate using WebBrowser Control? I want to open a C:\file1.html... an example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB code you have is correct, that is an error with the javascript on the page you are loading, so you can use:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "C:\file1.html"

End Sub
```

But in Form_Load set silent mode, eg:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

WebBrowser1.silent = true

End Sub
```

Comment: thanx friend i figured that too but forgot to post here. :D, thanx again

Answer (score 1):

i first put a webcomponent as mentioned in the post "*How do i open a webpage*" in vb6 by *adatapost*

Private Sub Command1_Click()

WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "C:\file1.html"

End Sub

this works but as u click on the button it pops  a error..A error has occured on the scirpt of the page , line 6, Error: object expected, url: file:///C:file1/index.html, do u want to continue , yes or NO............................how to come around this error. ??